# Magento2 Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object,

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am getting following error but not sure how to debug. Please guide.

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in app/code/XYZ/ElasticSmile/Model/Product/Indexer/Fulltext/Datasource/CatalogExtra.php on line 494
```

Here the function is

```
foreach ($product->getExtensionAttributes()->getConfigurableProductOptions() as $option) 
{
    $attributeCode = $option['product_attribute']->getAttributeCode();
    $options[$attributeCode] = $child->getData($attributeCode);
    //If you want to display swatch image, along with the option value, Do it here
}
```

Comment: Can you check if you got any result in this "$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getConfigurableProductOptions()" ??  because as per the error, you getting a null value.

Comment: That I checked it is null. But we have created some products in admin of configurable still why getting null?